# Number of point of intersection of $y=(x+2)$ and $y=(x+2)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The solution curve of the differential equation $\displaystyle (x^2+xy+4x+2y+4)\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2=0,x>0$
>
> Passes through the point $(1,3).$ Then
>
> $(1)$ number of point of intersection of  $y=x+2$
>
> $(2)$ number of point of intersection of $y=(x+2)^2$

Try: $$\bigg[(x+2)^2+y(x+2)\bigg]\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2$$

$$y^2\frac{dx}{dy}=(x+2)^2+y(x+2)$$

Could some help me to solve it , thanks

Comment: you can't just bop $\frac {dy}{dx}$ from one side to the other like that.

Comment: @DougM since this is an ODE not a PDE and it is true that $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}=\frac{dx}{dy}$ you can actually do this, you just sometimes have to be careful where $y=f(x)$ that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists fully

Answer (score 1):

$$y^2 \frac{dx}{dy} = (x+2)^2 + y(x+2)\\
\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{1}{y(x+2)} = \frac{1}{y^2}$$

Observe it is a linear differential equation by treating $\frac{-1}{x+2}$ as some variable $t$. Integration factor will be $\frac{1}{y}$ and solution is

$$\frac{-1}{(x+2)y} = \int \frac{dy}{y^3} = \frac{-1}{2y^2}-c\\
2y=(x+2)(cy^2+1)$$

I think you can proceed.