# Solve the diffrential equation $\left( {{x^2} + xy + 4x + 2y + 4} \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} - {y^2} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A solution curve of the differential equation $\left( {{x^2} + xy + 4x + 2y + 4} \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} - {y^2} = 0$, $x>0$ passes through the point (1,3). Find the solution curve.

I am not able to proceed as I am not able to convert the standard differentiable form

Comment: Hint: perform change of variable for each of $x=X-a$ and $y=Y-b$

Comment: Can I use $\left( {{x^2} + xy + 4x + 2y + 4} \right) = \left( {{{\left( {x + 2} \right)}^2} + y\left( {x + 2} \right)} \right)$

Comment: still not able to proceed

Comment: Maple's answer has a LambertW function in it. So I don't think you can expect an easy solution. But, maybe(?) there is a simplification which Maple doesn't apply.

Comment: Here is a graph of the solution in $[0,20]$. https://imgur.com/XddvPMb

Comment: I think that there is a problem in an answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632277/number-of-point-of-intersection-of-y-x2-and-y-x22?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left( {{x^2} + xy + 4x + 2y + 4} \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} - {y^2} = 0,$$

$$\left( {{{\left( {x + 2} \right)}^2} + y\left( {x + 2} \right)} \right)dy-y^2 dx=0$$

After substituting $x+2$ with $t$, we get
$$ (t^2+yt)dy-y^2dt=0$$
After multiplying with $t^{-2}$, we get
$$(1+\frac{y}{t})\frac{dy}{dt}-(\frac{y}{t})^2=0$$

Now use substitution $y=tu$, $y'=u+tu'$ from where is $(1+u)(u+tu')-u^2=0$
and
$$u+tu'=\frac{u^2}{u+1}$$
From here we get $$tu'=-\frac{u}{u+1}$$

and finally $$\frac{u+1}{u}du=-\frac{dt}{t}$$.

$$C+u+\ln{u}+\ln{t}=0$$

Comment: I am afraid that we do not agree. $y=u t \implies y'=u+u' t$ and not $u'+u' t$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, I will edit that.

Comment: Very fair, for sure

Comment: $$\ln \frac{y}{(x+2)^2}+1+\ln 3=\frac{x+2}{y}$$ is not a solution of the DE

Comment: @Raffaele. We are facing here an interesting situation. When the answer was accepted, the solution was wrong. I explained why in a comment. Answer reedited without a single word. Cheers :-)

Comment: Interesting ethical attitude.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @alans'answer
$$\left(1+\frac{y}{t}\right)y'-\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)^2=0$$ Using $y=t u$, this makes
$$(u+1) \left(t u'+u\right)-u^2=0$$ Switching variables
$$(u+1) \left(\frac t{t'}+u\right)-u^2=0\implies \frac {t'}t=-\frac{1}{u}-1$$
$$\log(t)+c=-u-\log (u)\implies k t=\frac{e^{-u}}{u}$$ This is the implicit solution.

If you want to go further, as already commented, you must use Lambert function; this would give
$$u=W\left(\frac{1}{k t}\right)$$ Back to $x$ and $y$
$$y=(x+2)\,W\left(\frac{1}{k (x+2) }\right)$$ Using the condition
$$3=3 \,W\left(\frac{1}{3k }\right)\implies k=\frac{1}{3 e}$$ SO, finally
$$y=(x+2)\,W\left(\frac{3e}{ x+2 }\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can use:
$$\left((x+2)^2+y(x+2)\right)\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2=0$$
if we first try with $$X=x+2,dX=dx:$$
$$(X^2+yX)\frac{dy}{dX}-y^2=0$$
$$X(X+y)\frac{dy}{dX}-y^2=0$$
this term of $X$ and $y$ together makes it quite hard to solve by hand

Comment: it is homogenous differential equation if you divide the both sides with $X^2$ and it is solvable.

Comment: Can we substitute y=VX

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi Yes, that I have done that in my answer.